# Code Migration issues from JBOSS (Java 6) to Websphere 8.5 (Java 6)

Tags: java, spring

Error:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
>   Context initialization failed
>                                    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/searchcenterTLSencha-servlet.xml]: Initialization
>   of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

XXXX-servlet.xml: (part of it)

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>resources/messages</value>
            <value>resources/application</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please someone assist me here, its been 2 days I spent time on this, still not able to figure out.

Appreciate your help..

Comment: There are a lot of things you haven't told us.  Suggestions: 1) consider modifying your (WebSphere-specific) WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml, and 2) look at these articles: [JNDI resource lookups in WebSphere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html), and [Using Spring and Hibernate with WebSphere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html)

Comment: Paste an original cause of exception in bottom of the stacktrace.